# Facebook error warning MY.URL.COM is unreachable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, facebook-comments

I have an interesting issue going on here. I'm trying to use facebook comments plugin on my website, and include the necessary meta tags required by Facebook (as far as I know) to work right.

What's interesting about this issue is that I don't get the warning on some pages and on others I do, and the only things that change are the pics and in some cases a description.

Now, if you could take a moment to look at these pages to see what I mean:

http://www.terrybrownmusic.com/photos/photo/146

displays just right, no errors.

But when you visit this page:

http://www.terrybrownmusic.com/photos/photo/147

I get the error at the comments section. Here is my .htaccess file IDK if it has anything to do with it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

any thoughts would be great guys. Thank you for your time!

[edit]

I just want to add that when I do get the debugger to work, It says that the `og:url` tag is not there, but it is!

Answer (score 0):

I see a different error when reviewing your URLs through the [Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.terrybrownmusic.com/photos/photo/147). It appears that you have added the page ID as the admin. This is incorrect, it should be your user-id (or one of the admin's user-id). Please refer here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Hi deesarus, I added the Admin ID and it doesn't even want to scrape it. The tags are there, but when I go to share it the pics won't show up. Sometimes it works fine, other times it just doesn't. I'm not sure what to do anymore. I went to look at another website's HTML and that website doesn't even have the meta tags and it works like a charm! lol, oh man. I'm having a really bad time with this. Your help is much appreciated.